# Android JNI ThrowNew doesn't find the constructor

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to throw an exception from the JNI, but the Activity crashes with the following logcat error:

```
WARNING: exception class 'Lthis/is/package/A$B;' missing constructor (msg='' kind=0
java.lang.RuntimeException: re-throw on exception class missing constructor
```

My code is similar to this:

In JAVA:

```
package this.is.package;
public class A {
    public class B extends Exception {
        public B () { super (); }
        public B ( String s ) { super ( s ); }
        public B ( Throwable t ) { super ( t ); }
        public B ( String s, Throwable t ) { super ( s, t ); }
    }
}
```

IN JNI:

```
(*env)->ThrowNew ( env, (*env)->FindClass ( "this/is/package/A$B" ), "" );
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When a java class is defined inside of another class, its constructors will be automatically appended with implicted args, e.g, parent class instance.

To solve this problem, just add `"static"` identifier/keyword to your class B:

e.g.
`public static class B extends Exception`